# write a clean junit4 tests

Tags: multithreading, unit-testing, junit4

with junit test , how could I start the application software then close it properly and do it for each test ?

- @test public void test1(){ // start
  appli //test Jtextfield //close appli
  }
- @test public void test2(){ // start
  appli //test ComboBox //close appli }
- @test public void test3{ // start
  appli //test Jbutton //close appli

}

Comment: I think you're missing the point of a unit test.  You don't instantiate your *main application*; you *create* a small application with just the things needed to test a behaviour.

Comment: I created the main in another class where I start a thread as follow :  @BeforeClass
 public static void setupOnce() {
  final Thread thread = new Thread() {

   public void run() {   
    //start the appli in the main}thread.start();

Comment: I think you're missing the point of a unit test.

Comment: and my test class extends this first class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally there are means of doing some action before and after test class / test method passing in junit 4 (see info about @BeforeClass and @BeforeMethod annotations, for example, here: http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html)

But application starting/stopping behavior looks closer to functionality testing, not unit testing. Probably it would be better not to start and stop whole application, but perform some application reinitialization.

Also, there's perfect functionality testing framework TestNG (http://testng.org), and it also provides means like beforeclass / beforemethod annotations.